# "Mac-style" unzipping on linux

Tags: linux-mint, osx, zip

I'm using Linux Mint MATE edition, in case that's relevant.

I don't know if this is Dropbox specific, but when i download a zip of a folder that was originally produced on a Mac (and that has lots of nested subfolders) from dropbox, and unzip it on my Linux machine, it's completely messed up:  all folders have a duplicate with a downcased version of their name, and the subfiles appear in the duplicate instead of the original.  If one of my Mac-owning colleagues unzips that same zip, then it's fine.

This is what i should get:

[image]

And this is what i actually get:

[image]

My guess is that this is somehow related to the fact that Macs are non-case-sensitive with file names, and thus there's some weird incompatibility between file system metadata, or something.

Does anyone know of a linuz unzip tool which replicates the behaviour of the Mac unzipper, or otherwise produces the correct result?  I don't mind if it leaves the_MACOSX folder in there (i can just delete these), as long as the main folder is fine.

Comment: ciopfs is not a command on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 3):

It does look like the problem is that the zip file uses inconsistent case variations for directory names. This is exactly what the [ciopfs](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/) filesystem is for: it provides a case-insensitive view of a directory tree. There's an Ubuntu package. Create a view of an existing directory by mounting the ciopfs filesystem on a temporary directory, unpack the zip inside that view, and you'll get the archive extracted in the original directory.

```
mkdir ~/case-insensitive
ciopfs ~/temp ~/case-insensitive
cd ~/case-insensitive
unzip -x __MACOSX -x '__MACOSX/*' /path/to/zip
cd ~/temp
fusermount -u ~/case-insensitive
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, my next candidate would be the [Python `zipfile` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146264/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-zip-to-a-tar-without-extracting-it-to-the-filesystem/146274#146274)).

Comment: It seems it simply lowercases all files even it non conflicting file don't exist. That's a bit unfortunate for files which need to have a certain casing. Otherwise a good suggestion!