# Unzip and rename a particular directory in zip --- in one operation

Tags: directory, tar, zip, mv, stdout

Say I have `archive.zip` that contains a directory named `myDir` (it's actually the only directory inside it) and that this directory contains a file named `x`.

`unzip archive.zip -d ~/` brings:

```
~/myDir/x
```

`mv ~/myDir ~/myRenamedDir`, brings:

```
~/myRenamedDir/x
```

---

Is there a way to rename my `myDir` with the extraction, so the outcome would be `~/myRenamedDir/x`, directly, without needing `mv`?

Comment: has `/x` directory any subfolders?

Comment: There isn't anything that's going to significantly speed the process up. It's a difference of fractions of a second

Comment: If you're not tied to using `zip` archives, you could use `tar` and its powerful `--transform` feature.

Comment: Yes @RomanPerekhrest it has.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using `unzip`’s `-j` option:

> **`-j`**
>
>     junk paths. 
>       The archive’s directory structure is not recreated; all files are deposited in the extraction directory (by default, the current one).
>
> <sub>Source: [unzip(1)](https://man.cx/unzip)</sub>

```
unzip -d ~/myRenameDir/ -j  <FILE>
```

Comment: @user9303970 the zipfile name should come after the options

Comment: Hmm, thanks, this worked, I think the answer should be edited with this data.

Comment: @user9303970 that is standard `unzip` usage: Only the `-x` and `-d` options may come after the zip filename. Every other option has to come before.

Answer (score 1):

Anthon has written [a nice script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146274/260978) for converting zip files to tar files. With a couple of modifications, you can use to convert a zip to tar and send the tar file in a pipe to `tar`, and if you have GNU `tar`, you can use the `--transform` flag to rename things.

The modifications: use `w|` as the mode so that we can write to stdout, and use `sys.stdout` as a file object for opening the tar file:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

"""zip2tar """

import sys
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
import tarfile
import time

def main(ifn):
    with ZipFile(ifn) as zipf:
        with tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdin, mode='w|') as tarf:
            for zip_info in zipf.infolist():
                #print zip_info.filename, zip_info.file_size
                tar_info = tarfile.TarInfo(name=zip_info.filename)
                tar_info.size = zip_info.file_size
                tar_info.mtime = time.mktime(list(zip_info.date_time) +
                                         [-1, -1, -1])
                # zip files don't have permissions, so
                # make everything executable for now
                tar_info.mode=0755
                tarf.addfile(
                    tarinfo=tar_info,
                    fileobj=zipf.open(zip_info.filename)
                )

main(sys.argv[1])
```

Save this as, say, `zip2tar.py`, make it executable, and you could do:

```
zip2tar.py archive.zip | tar x -C ~ --transform 's/^myDir/myRenameDir/'
```

Or if `~/myRenameDir` already exists:

```
zip2tar.py archive.zip | tar x -C ~/myRenameDir --strip-components=1
```